# Display a clickable list in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I've a fragment where a clickable list should get displayed.
The list comes from the method `List<Location> getAllLocations()`.

A `Location`-Element comes from a database and looks like the following:

```
id: 1
name: Example
description: A long Description
Geo: Latitude: 46.685984999999995 Longitude: 7.867318999999998
```

It should only be the name & the description get displayed. When i click on it, it should be open in a `DetailView` (this view is finished and works).

How i realise a ViewList like this?

**Fragment Code**

```
public class EditSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public EditSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment, container,
                false);


        return view;
    }
}
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
Implement the ListAdapter. added a big list of methods and getting confused about it.

```
public class EditSectionFragment extends Fragment implements ListAdapter {

    public EditSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ListFragment` fill the data using a ListAdapter or CursorAdapter

have you tried to follow this [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) ?

Make sure you implement the `onListItemClick`-method when using the ListFragment

Comment: I tried it. But i'm confused about my art of fragment. in no tutorial is a fragment used like mine. i need it tomorrow and nothing works. i'm getting desperate...

Comment: So i should implement the ListFragment? look at my code. and now? i don't find any tutorial which helps me...